# How to get history command in fish shell to work?

Tags: macos, command-line, big-sur, fish

On one of my Macs, the `history` command in the `fish` shell doesn't seem to be working, it does nothing:

```
~> echo foo
~> echo bar
~> history
~>
```

On another, both running Big Sur, it works fine, displaying a list of recent commands in a pager.

In both cases I installed `fish` from Homebrew.

**Question**: What could be causing this? I checked and both the `less` and `more` commands work fine, one of which I guess `history` needs...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I have done `export PAGER=less` and `history save`, haven't narrowed it down yet which one, but one of these commands have fixed it.

Just leaving it here for anyone looking for a solution to the same problem.